# Restore SQL Server database backup to Windows Azure VM

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I created an instance of SQL Server 2012 Std Sp1 & Windows Server 2012 VM package on Windows Azure evaluation version.

Then I connected to the SQL Server running on Windows Azure using my local SQL Server 2012 (Evaluation copy) installed.

Question: when I try to restore a backup from a `.bak` file (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Database.bak`) to SQL Server running on Windows Azure, it doesn't even list the above file under SQL Server Management Studio > Restore Database > Select Backup from a File > Add > locate Backup file.

What is that?

May I know how can I restore my backup file stored in my local PC to the SQL Server running on VM instance of Windows Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you copied the backup to the VM first? The view from within SQL Server Management Studio is that of the server's local disks. Copy the backup to the server (copy/paste using remote desktop works) and then restore as usual.

Comment: Hi Dean, Nope. Does it mean that when I connected to the SQL server in Windows Azure VM using SQL Server Management Studio in my local PC, it presents the Windows Azure VM server C:\ drive?

Comment: That's right. It's the same if you connect to an on-site remote server too.

Comment: Thanks, I got the scenarios now.